# Very strange behavior with WinForms ListBox and Ctrl+C keypress

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm experiencing some very strange behavior in a WinForms `ListBox` in two of my applications.  They both have some other controls (`TableLayoutPanel`s, `Button`s, etc.)

Both applications handle the Ctrl+C keystroke to copy the selected item(s) of the `ListBox` to the clipboard.  When I press Ctrl+C, though, the selected index of the current `ListBox` moves down by one, or if the last item is selected, the selection wraps around to the first item.  This happens *after* my `KeyDown` handler does its work.

This is very strange because there's no code in either application that would cause this behavior.  I don't even know what key to press to make the selection advance or wrap like that.

I've been trying to reproduce this behavior in a sample program, but so far I haven't been able to figure out what these two applications have in common that makes them behave this way.  If I figure it out, I will update this question accordingly.

I compared the Windows message activity between an application that has this problem and an application that doesn't.  I found one specific message that is causing it:

```
msg=0x2111 (WM_REFLECT + WM_COMMAND)
hwnd=0x211e2
wparam=0x111e2
lparam=0x211e2
result=0x0
```

Here are the full message logs from pressing Ctrl+C in each program:

- Message log WITH this problem: https://gist.github.com/2854221
- Message log WITHOUT this problem: https://gist.github.com/2854203

I can prevent this mystery message from being handled, but what is it, and what causes it to be sent?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you try to add a temporary event handler to the ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged event to see which code changed the selection?

Comment: Yes... it's in native code and the `base.WndProc` method.  I have something better though - I just updated the question with the exact Windows message that causes the behavior.

Answer (score -2):

The list box manage the key press, so when the new selected item starts with "c"

Comment: No, that's not what's going on.  My list items don't start with `C`, the selected index always increases by one or wraps rather than moving to a specific item, and this behavior only happens when pressing `Ctrl+C`, not just `C`.